# Evaluate $\int \frac{e^{2x}-1}{\sqrt{e^{2x}-(x+1)^2}} dx $

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

> Evaluate 
>   $$\int \frac{e^{2x}-1}{\sqrt{e^{2x}-(x+1)^2}} dx $$

Now, what I've checked is the derivative of $\sqrt{e^{2x}-(x+1)}$ = $\frac{2e^{2x}-1}{2\sqrt{e^{2x}-(x+1)}}$ which kind of gives me a way to start but it is not much . Any hints will be appreciated !

The problem  is from a Romanian  Mathematical Gazette from a older edition  called  in my language "Gazeta Matematica" ( I don't know if I wrote the name correctly in english)  . It pretty much publishes problems for  the olympiad.

Comment: Wolfram very strongly believes no answer exists in terms of any of the functions in its library.

Comment: Sorry for not answering, it is from a Romanian  Mathematical Gazette from a older edition  called  in my language "Gazeta Matematica" ( I don't know if I wrote the name correctly in english)  . It pretty much publishes problems for  the olympiad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$I=\int \frac{e^{2x}-1}{\sqrt{e^{2x}-(1+x)^2}} dx$$
Let $$J=\int \frac{e^{2x}-(1+x)}{\sqrt{e^{2x}-(1+x)^2}}dx$$
Let $$e^{2x}-(1+x)^2=t \implies 2[e^{2x}-(1+x)] dx=dt$$
$$\implies J=\int \frac {dt}{2\sqrt{t}} dt =\sqrt{e^{2x}-(1+x)^2}$$
next note that $$I=J-K, ~~ K=\int \frac{x dx}{\sqrt{e^{2x}-(1+x)^2}}=\int \frac{x e^{-x}dx}{\sqrt{1-e^{-2x}(1+x)^2}}$$
Let $e^{-x}(1+x)=u \implies -xe^{-x} dx =du$, then
$$K=-\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}=-\sin^{-1}[e^{-x} (1+x)]$$
Finally, $$I=\sqrt{e^{2x}-(1+x)^2}+ \sin [e^{-x} (1+x)]+C$$

Comment: Please modify this expression:  $e^{-x}(1+x)=u \implies -xe^{-x} dx =du$

Comment: $User041025  Thanks fir the edit.

Comment: Interesting approach, thank you ! Just curious, how did you manage to define J and K ( what made you think to write the indefinite integrals like that )  ?

Comment: @Jan9 If yoi follow this, you will be able to solvesome other problem like this. Some times difference of two integrals is do-able.

Comment: Thank you for your help !